# Heap / C++ Standard Library use Under Green Hills INTEGRITY

Tags: c++, integrity, greenhills

I'm running under Green Hills INTEGRITY 5.0.10 targeting a Marvell Monahans PXA 320. For development, I'm using MULTI 4.2.3 and my language of choice is C++.

I'm just learning about INTEGRITY memory management and am wondering about use of dynamic memory.

I would like to use std::string, std::map, etc. Of course, these require a heap. May I use these classes? More generally, may I use the heap directly (new / delete)?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I have never used INTEGRITY but is there anything preventing you from creating a custom allocator then passing that to std::string or std::map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Green Hills is not targeting the super-tiny, severely resource-constrained embedded microcontrollers with their INTEGRITY OS or MULTI IDE, so in their market they wouldn't get very far if their proprietary C++ compiler didn't support STL or a heap in general.  The following web pages seem to support this:

http://www.ghs.com/news/20030915_m40.html

http://www.ghs.com/news/20041116_mobileye.html

So I'd say "Yes, you may use std::string, std::map, malloc(), new, etc."

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I develop on INTEGRITY 5.0.11 and Multi 4.2.4 and you can use all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use all the STD library, and you can compile it with or without exception support. It also supports the japanese automotive standard, on which I don't know very much about.

From mid-2017 Green Hills compiler supports also C++11, I can't tell you very much on how well is supported because we are still transitioning